# How do I set array arguments into variables using Java

Tags: java, arrays, variables, split

I want to take this string "John Doe and Eli Manning", and using `split()` on the String to store the elements of the array into variables.

I already know how to do the first part

```
String str = "John Doe and Eli Manning"; 
String tokens[] = str.split("and");
```

Now I have an array ["Kevin Suffredini", "Eli Manning"]. I want to set those two elements into separate variables that I can use. What is the syntax for this?

something like?? :

```
String person1 = ...arg[0];
String person2 = ...arg[1];
```

Comment: Well it'd be `String person1 = tokens[0];` not arg[0].

Comment: Actually, you'd have `John Doe` and `Eli Manning`. :D

Answer (score 4):

Use the `tokens` array you defined, like

```
String p1 = tokens[0];
String p2 = tokens[1];
```

You probably want to make sure your `tokens` array has 2 items in it.

Also, you can't dynamically create variables if you can have an arbitrary amount tokens, but you can loop over tokens and get each String in the array.